# Use design patterns in Genexus 9 java / web

Tags: genexus

I need to know if is possible to implement design patterns in genexus (e.g prototype or singleton) and how.

Comment: I don't think I understood your question... What do you mean by "singleton"? GeneXus is not object-oriented... Or you mean a "singleton" as a one-record table in the database?

Comment: Thanks for anwser, i mean design pattern singleton (https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton) how can implement this (or equivalent) in Gx

Comment: The problem with your question is that you need an object-oriented language to use the Singleton pattern, which GeneXus is not... There is no meaning for "singleton" when you can't create objects.

Answer (score 0):

Genexus is a software, which helps you design your code. So you describe your business requirements, and it is the responsibility of this software to generate the code.
"Design Patterns" are used during designing, so it is best left to this designing software to use it.